# How can I solve this special integral?

Tags: calculus

How can I prove that the result of this integral is equal to zero. I know that this function is odd function. So it must be zero but I have tried something, but i couldn't solve it. Could you suggest a way to solve it ?

$\int _{-\infty }^{\infty }\dfrac {xe^{x}} {\left( e^{x}+1\right) }dx$

Comment: It's not an odd function.

Comment: Wait... this integral isn't even defined, as $1-e^{-x}=0$ at $x=0$

Comment: @vrugtehagel But the $x$ in the numerator cancels the zero of the denominator. However, $\frac{x}{1-e^{-x}} > x$ for $x > 0$, so the integral is infinite.

Comment: @vrugtehagel ... and $x=0$ at $x=0$. The function $\frac{x}{1-e^{-x}}$ can be made continuous at $x=0$.

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+x%2F(1-exp(-x))+from+-infinty+to+infinity

Comment: i am sorry. You are right Daniel Fisher. I am just litte confused. I asked wrong integral to you. I edited. I am so sorry again.

Comment: It's $$\frac{x}{1 + e^{-x}}$$ not $1 - e^{-x}$

Answer (score 1):

The integral is not zero. Also it does not converge.
Indeed, as a try, let's collect $e^x$:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{x e^{x}}{e^{x}(1 + e^{-x})}\ \text{d}x = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{x}{1 + e^{-x}}\ \text{d}x$$

Sure you got rid of $e^x$ but since this is not an odd function, you cannot split the integral in the two parts, and also the integral is not zero. Simply it does not converge. It's regular in zero, but not at the infinite.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Divide into pieces

$-\infty,0$ and $0,\infty$

Set $x=-y$ in the first and then add the two integrals